# Beam apply PTransform to values while preserving key

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I seem to be struggling with this pattern in Beam. This is a streaming pipeline.

At a high level:

- message comes in to Rabbit
- message contents include an ID and N S3 file paths
- I want to produce some aggregation across all S3 files listed, but the results should be keyed by original message
- write a message back to rabbit with the aggregation result, one for each incoming message

Inevitably, I end up with some `PCollection[KV[MessageId, S3FilePaths]]` and want to apply a bunch of `PTransform`s on the `S3FilePaths` but not lose the fact that they were originally keyed by `MessageId`.

I can't seem to find a generic "map the values of a KV pcollection but retain the key" functionality, and I believe I *have* to use a PTransform (as opposed to a `DoFn`) because file IO has all been implemented as PTransforms.

Am I fundamentally thinking about this the wrong way? Any help is much appreciated.

---

**Update**: Sorry for being light on details. My own fault for posting this at the end of a frustrating Friday.

I had a few fundamental stumbling blocks:

1. I've realized that `PCollection[KV` is really for combining already-loaded data. Trying to isolate each `V` as a separate set of pipeline operations didn't really mesh with the API
2. I didn't have my global windowing/triggering set up appropriately for the task at hand. Moreso, my transforms were not always preserving the window/pane semantics I had assumed.
3. I have distinct s3 file paths coming in for each message, but due to issues like https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-7753, the `FileIO` APIs being oriented around `PTransform`s which do not easily allow me to tag results with the incoming message id, and being unable to instantiate `ReadableFile` directly (it's package-private) I couldn't piece it together. I ended up wrapping the S3 client for java inside a custom `PTransform` that preserves the original `MessageId` along with each returned value.

At this point, I have something working end-to-end. My code is actually written in [scio](https://github.com/spotify/scio) so it's a bit tricky to share, but at a high level:

1. reading from RabbitMQ using a `Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane())` trigger in a fixed, 1-second window, and being careful to use `ProcessContext.output` to preserve windowing and timestamps throughout
2. Utilizing the general shape of `PCollection[(MessageId, V)]` (scala `Tuple2` syntax) throughout. When `V` is a path to an S3 file, I utilize a `PTransform` from the path emitting the contents of the file (it's an unsupported data format)
3. Aggregations are done after grouping to `PCollection[KV[(MessageId, FileElementId), FileElement]]` and then reduced back down to `PCollection[MessageId, FileElement]` so that the semantics of reducing per incoming message are retained.

Number 2 was a tad disappointing to me. I was hoping to be able to utilize beam Filesystem functions to read from a file and combine each output with the message id it was specified in. But I'm in a good spot now.

Comment: Hi there, can you please edit your post with your pipeline code? It would help out immensely.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to apply transforms to a `KV<KeyT, ValueT>` if they only accept a `KeyT` or `ValueT`. If you need to retain the key while applying transforms on the value, then the recommended approach is to either write your own `DoFns` that can accept a `KV` but ignore the key, or restructure your pipeline so that you don't rely on the output of transforms that require dropping the keys.